# Axios GET method with Laravel and Vue.JS returning 404 error in javascript console

Tags: laravel, vue.js, get, axios

I'm getting the following error:

> GET http://backend.test/test?last_name=DOE 404 (Not Found)

When trying the following GET method:

My GET request in Vue.JS:

```
    testMethod: _.debounce(async function () {
      await axios.get('test', { params: { last_name: 'DOE' } })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }, 50),
```

The route in Laravel:

```
Route::get('test/{params}', 'TestController@filter');
```

The method in my Laravel's `TestController.php` (not passed):

```
    public function filter($params)
    {
        Log::info($params);
    }
```

What's wrong with it ?

=== EDIT ===

If I rewrite the route like this:

```
Route::get('test/{params?}', 'TestController@filter');
```

Then I get the following error in Laravel logs:

> [2020-04-26 21:28:48] local.ERROR: Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\TestController::filter(), 0 passed and
>   exactly 1 expected {"userId":1,"exception":"[object]
>   (ArgumentCountError(code: 0): Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\TestController::filter(), 0 passed and
>   exactly 1 expected at
>   /Users/me/code/backend/app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php:10)

Comment: what does it say when you add `?` to params like, {params?} - you are not sending params, just sending query string.

Comment: @Ersoy I have just updated my post to reply your question.

Comment: Please update your controller method to accept Request to and remove params - and try to log with $request->toArray();

Comment: That works perfect. Thanks a lot! Maybe you can post it as an answer ?

Comment: glad to hear that, i will post an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Route::get('test/{params}', 'TestController@filter');` route expects `params` to be mandotary; adding `?` to `params` will make it optional.

> `Route::get('test/{params?}', 'TestController@filter');`

To fetch `last_name`, it is required to update controller method as following;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $request->get('last_name');
        // actions
    }
}
```